# how to write Couchbase`s Spatial view

Tags: couchbase, couchbase-view

could i write like this?

```
function (doc,meta) {

emit([[doc.range1, doc.range2],[doc.range3, doc.range4]], doc.comment); 

}
```

i just want to find data use two range.I found a example that is

```
emit([10.9, 48.4, [1000, 2000]], null);
```

the range  [1000,2000] does it can filter data?

Answer (score 0):

The following link will help: http://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/4.0/sdks/dotnet-2.2/geo-spatial-views.html

And remember, spatial feature is experimental before version 4.0. 
For use with python, in my case, it provides `SpatialQuery` object.
(from couchbase.views.params import SpatialQuery)

Answer (score 0):

supposing you have a json document shaped this way

```
{
  "resourceId": "3c0d9906-4e88-4b12-b96b-9d7377a503a9", 
  "_type": "com.sample.model.Position",
  "updated": 1510790620782,
  "point": {
  "coordinates": [15.704621,40.2755],
 "type": "Point"
 }
}
```

you can write a spatial view this way

```
function (doc) {
if (typeof doc.point !== 'undefined' && doc._type == "com.sample.model.Position") {
    var date = Date.parse(doc.updated) / 1000;
    emit(doc.point, doc.resourceId);
    }
}
```

you can use the browser to design your docuement:
go to http://localhost:8091
enter index -> view menu
from there you can test the view with real document from your data
this create the index; to query the index you can use the geo funcions even with rest as described by

[official documentation](https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/4.1/views/sv-query-parameters.html)

hope it helps